# Change the fill alpha value of a point/shape based on the distance from its center or border in ggplot (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working with maps and I'd like to represent the decreasing power of something as the distance from its center increases (in a continuous fashion, the particular rate at which it decreases doesn't matter too much). You could think of it like the "hardness" setting of a brush on image editing software. Instead of a circle having a hardness of 100%, I would like something between 0 and 100.

I'm currently working with the sf package to make some maps of the following basic form:

```
ggplot() +
  annotation_spatial(mapdata) +
  layer_spatial(mapdata)
```

And upon this map I want to add a point as described above. Is there a way to work with the alpha fill values of something like `annotate("point",...)` or `geom_circle()` to achieve this?

Comment: 1.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, we need some test data.  2.  points have no fill aesthetic in `ggplot2`, so you can't change their `fill` alpha.  You may be able to modify the `colour` alpha *between* points.  3.  AFAIK You can't adjust the fill *within* a shape that corresponds to a single row of the input data frame.  You *may* be able to achieve what you want by overlaying multiple rows.

Comment: @Limey I'm not sure what a minimal reproducible example would be in my case, since I'm agnostic as to the exact ggplot tool/method used to get such a circle. If a solution is possible, I don't think my use-case really even matters, as it would be possible to do with an empty plot and a unit circle at (0,0) (from which I could adapt it to my use-case). 

I could potentially do what you're saying in 3 and just make many successively larger borderless circles each with a low alpha value, so that their alphas sum to make a "continuous" gradient. I will try this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a custom annotation of a `circleGrob` with a `radialGradient`:

```r
soft_circle <- grid::circleGrob(
  x = 0.75, y = 0.25, r = 0.25, gp = grid::gpar(
  fill = grid::radialGradient(colours = c("#ff0000a0", "#ff000080", "#00000000"),
                              stops = c(0, 0.5, 1)), 
  lwd = 0))
```

Allowing

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = 10, returnclass = "sf")) +
  geom_sf(fill = "cornsilk") +
  annotation_custom(soft_circle) +
  geom_sf(fill = NA, color = "black") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-15, 5), ylim = c(49, 60))
```

[image]

You can change the "hardness" by adjusting the `stops` argument of the radial gradient. For example, this:

```r
soft_circle <- grid::circleGrob(
  x = 0.75, y = 0.25, r = 0.1, gp = grid::gpar(
  fill = grid::radialGradient(colours = c("red", "red", "#00000000"),
                              stops = c(0, 0.75, 1)), 
  lwd = 0))
```

results in

[image]